Nonzero entire function such that $a_n=f(n)$
A friend of mine came out with this riddle: does there exist a nonzero entire function $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k x^k$ such that for all nonnegative integer $n$, $f(n)=a_n$?
I reformulated the problem as following: if $\phi_{n,k}$ is $k^n$ when $n \neq k$ and $k^n-1$ otherwise, then $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k \phi_{n,k} = 0$ for all $n$, which means the sequence $a$ is orthogonal to all the sequences $\phi_n$. If the adherence of the vector subspace generated by the $\phi_n$’s was big enough, this could imply that $a$ is zero. I tried approximating arbitrary functions that converge to zero by scaled down versions of the $\phi_n$’s (dividing them by a factorial to “tame” them) but I do not get anywhere with this approach.
Maybe some tool that relates the asymptotics of $a$ and $f$ could exploit the hypothesis in a more effective way.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91855/442  [similar, but not the same]

so, what's your question? for help with your friend's riddle?

@mathworker21 Indeed, as I was not able to solve it by myself.

We can construct such a function as a Fourier transform
$$
f(z)=\int_{-\pi L}^{\pi L} g(t) e^{itz}\, dt, \quad g\in L^2 .
$$
Then $g$ needs to be orthogonal to all $h_n(t)=(it)^n/n!-e^{int}$, so we must show that $\{ h_n\}$ does not span $L^2(-\pi L,\pi L)$. This looks plausible because the $h_n$ are small perturbations of the exponentials, which come from the complete ONS $\{ e^{ikt/L}: k\in\mathbb Z \}$, but we are using only a fraction $1/L$ of these.
Let $k_n=h_n/\|h_n\|$. Then
$$
\langle k_n, k_j\rangle = \delta_{nj}+O(C^n/(n!j))+O(C^j/(j!n)) .
$$
Fix a large $N$. This estimate then shows that $\| \sum_{j=N}^{N+n} \alpha_j k_j \|$ is comparable to $\|\alpha\|_2$,
and this in turn implies that we can not get close to any of the other exponentials $e^{ikt/L}$, $k\not\equiv 0\bmod L$, with such linear combinations.
